# Go vendoring outside $GOPATH

Tags: go

I have a project which is built in Node.js/Express.js. I want to start to rewrite this to go/iris framework. I don't want to re-factor everything into my $GOPATH and I want to keep it together my express / go / docker files for this project.

I tried to clone iris framework's git repo into a `./vendor` subfolder, but using `import "github.com/kataras/iris"` importing nothing.

Is there a package manager which is

- copying and installing packages and all of it's dependencies in `my-project/vendor` folder **outside $GOPATH**
- it can update these import packages
- `go run/build/install` outside $GOPATH
- there's now any new files in $GOPATH `src/pkg/bin` folder when I working on a project, except this package manager
- I can define dependency packages for a project like `package.json` file for `node.js`

Is there a go package manager like that?

Edit:

Running this with `go` command is not required.

Comment: If you want to use the default go tools, don't try to work around GOPATH. Otherwise you might be interested in https://getgb.io/

Comment: Vendoring is not supported outside of the `$GOPATH`: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12511

Comment: put it in your gopath and symlink `ln -s $GOPATH/src/github.com/lanti/project ~/dev/project`

Comment: This is not work in Windows environments.

Comment: @lanti can you use git-bash or similar to make it work?

Comment: I try to work with `gb` package manager now. It's a little bit buggy in windows, but in theory this is the nearest thing what I want.

Comment: This is probably more closest to `npm` than `gb`: https://github.com/skelterjohn/wgo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible with the current go tooling, but looks like we might get it in go 1.12 or bit later.

Proposal accepted:

[cmd/go: modify the Go toolchain to work without GOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17271)